# Getting error in button position change in swift 3

Tags: ios, button, swift3, position

I'm using the below-mentioned code for changing the position of button in swift 3 for 6s but I got the error like this Value of type '(Any) -> ()' has no member 'frame'. I'm stuck here

```
if screenHeight == 667{

  //  self.forgetPasswordBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 25, width: screenWidth, height: 30)
        nextBtn.frame.origin = CGRect(x:0,y:0)

    }
```

Comment: It shows the same error...

Comment: (Any) -> ()  is a swift closure. Of course it has no member 'frame'. Is your nextBtn has type UIButton? Where did you get this nextBtn?

Comment: How did you declare "nextBtn"? The error you're showing indicates that the variable nextBtn wasn't properly declared as a UIButton (I'm assuming that's the class you wanted).

Comment: Yeah I have declared it as the UIbutton..

Comment: Please show the code with the declaration for nextBtn.  The error looks like an issue with the declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type cast your Any type instance with UIButton like

```
if let btn = nextBtn as? UIButton {
   btn.frame.origin = CGRect(x:0,y:0)
}
```

Then you are able to access 'frame' property.

Answer (score 1):

origin is a CGPoint, not a CGRect

You'd need to do something like:

```
button.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var newRect: CGRect = nextBtn.frame

newRect.origin.x = newRect.origin.x - 100 // do whatever you want either + or -
newRect.origin.y = newRect.origin.y - 100 // do whatever you want either + or -


nextBtn.frame = newRect
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    button.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
```

it works for me ,can you show detail for the error ?

Comment: Value of type '(Any) -> ()' has no member 'frame'

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can not set the origin like this , you have to set frame of your button. And after all `origin` is the `CGPoint` not `CGRect`. So change you code with below and try.

```
nextBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: nextBtn.frame.size.width, height: nextBtn.frame.size.height)
```

Comment: It gets the error in nextBtn. Value of type '(Any) -> ()' has no member 'frame'

Comment: @imacapple can you show me your nextBtn declaration

Answer (score 1):

CGRect used when want to change frame in view.

When want to change origin use CGPoint because origin is position in view.

Code for that is below.

```
if screenHeight == 667{
        nextBtn.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    }
```